# Linux From Scratch is right place to start?

Tags: linux, distro

I want to create my custom linux distro. Should i start with 'Linux From scratch ' project ?

Comment: Why?  What are you specific reasons?

Comment: Please take a look at this site http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/, but first give us please your reasons

Comment: Really? Another one? Have you already checked http://lwn.net/Distributions/ and/or http://distrowatch.com/ ?

Comment: As Zoredache says, you're going to need a LOT more information to get any realistic help with this.  Do you have any limitations (want this to fit on one of those 40MB "business card" CDs, want it to PXE boot)? Do you want to have a distro designed for a specific feature (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Terminal_Server_Project )?

Comment: You should start with a copy of Minix, the Lions book, and some time on an old DECStation. Anything else is taking the easy way out, don't you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently the concept of JeOS (just enough OS) emerged - providing only the smallest set of packages needed to get a GNU/Linux system running. Ubuntu, SuSE and others offer JeOS images of their distribution that can be tailored to build appliances and/or provide building blocks that could still be identified as being Ubuntu, SLES, etc. Novell even offers a web interface for building SLES JeOS based appliances on their machines. Even of JeOS are particularly suited to be run in virtualized environments due to their lightweight nature they can still be used to get something really tailored to a given need. Generally speaking it can be quite difficult to provide the integration that can be found in a decent distro to anything comparable.

That being said there's nothing quite like the experience one gets by trying to get something out from LFS.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to make a Debian Pure Blend. You can read more [about it here](http://blends.alioth.debian.org/blends/). You get your customizations plus all the good stuff from Debian.
You can use the tools and ideas from the page I linked to generate a Blend of your own.

Other option is using [Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org) or another small distro as basis for a LiveCD or distro.

Answer (score 0):

I would give Calculate Linux Scratch a try -> http://www.calculate-linux.org/main/en/cls